# Files pushed to repository with git not visible on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, rstudio

I have a problem with my git repository on Bitbucket. When I try to open the files I pushed to the empty repository I just created I get the following error:

> Hmm... can't find that one
>   That file or directory doesn’t exist. Go back to the previous page and try another one.

This is the same for all files apart from the readme.md file which opens without any issue. I can see all the files in the bitbucket directory that I pushed from my local directory including the files details (name/size/last commit/message) which are all correct. I i click to open the file it gives me the same error for each one.

If I go to the commit menu in Bitbucket for the repository I can see that all the files were added with the correct amount of lines for each file and the contents of each file highlighted in green. If i click on view file button, on each individual file here it takes me to the file...?

I have tried deleting the bitbucket repository and starting again with the same result. 
Steps to failure:
- In RStudio select version control for my R-project, restart RStudio.
- In bash: `git add --all`
- `git commit -m "Comment"`

```
[master (root-commit) 371afd5] Comment
 14 files changed, 828 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 file.R
 create mode 100644 README.md
 create mode 100644 file1.R
 create mode 100644 dummyfile.md
 create mode 100644 file2.R
 create mode 100644 load.R
 create mode 100644 file3.R
 create mode 100644 file4.R
 create mode 100644 options.yml
 create mode 100644 run.R
 create mode 100644 script.R
 create mode 100644 stitch.csv
 create mode 100644 file5.R
 create mode 100644 file6.R
```

- git push --mirror

Same result, unable to open files in the bitbucket repository

I deleted the Bitbucket repository.
I also deleted the local .git directory.
Trying again following instructions from here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-unversioned-code-to-a-repository-877177133.html
I still ended up with the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate the "New source browser experience BETA" feature.

**Click on your Account profile pic (Bottom left) -> click "BitBucket Labs" -> scroll to "New source browser experience BETA", then turn it off.**

Everything will be back :)

Comment: This worked straight away! Thanks so much, I spent two days trying to setup/delete repositories and change settings! Thank you

Comment: I too wasted a lot of time on this.. happy to share:D

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue as you are right now. Some of the folders in my repository are okay, but there few that I added later started showing this error, where they show the message you mentioned.

I started having this problem, when I started using VS Code built-in Git to push the changes to the repository. But even recreating the repository it still throws the same errors.

The funny thing is, that if you try cloning the repository into a new folder, it all comes back okay, with all the folders and files. So I am guessing this is some sort of a problem in Bitbucket site.

Hoping they fix it soon.

Comment: The solution below worked for me so I hope it works for you also!

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in bitbucket with publilc repo. I just updated the avatar and repo description and refresh the link. It'll work fine.